# cron-job linux apache ssl

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, drupal, cron

I have a server installed with apache2 and drupal 6. In my server, I have installed a module which need to use cron. I have a SSL certificate installed too.

In my crontab y have this configuration:

```
* * * * * wget -O --q -t 1 http://domain:8280/folder/cron.php
* * * * * wget --no-check-certificate -O --q -t 1 https://domain/folder/cron.php
```

My server work but if I write this configuration in my sites-enabled/000-default:

```
redirect permanent / https://domain/
```

my module with cron stops working. This is my error in syslog:

```
grandchild #20349 failed with status 5
```

I need to redirect my traffic from http to https.

Comment: First, make sure your redirect configuration is correct (see [Apache wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL)) and doesn't interfere with configuration in .htaccess.
Second, create a standalone scripts for your cron tasks and put them somewhere in your $PATH ( /usr/local/ or something). Also, make sure your scripts are executable (chmod +x ...) and they work properly, when run under your webserver's user (sudo -u www-data /usr/local/your-wget-task.sh). And last but not least, make sure you understand what your wget command is doing. I'm not sure -O option works without output file

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I think that my redirect configuration is correct. When I try to access to htp://domain my server redirect me to htps://domain correctly. I think that my script cron.php is ok too, If I don't write my redirect configuration in 000-default my module with cron-job works without problem.

Comment: If you enable redirect in your 000-default.conf, then try to comment out first line in your crontab, and change command in the second one to this: `wget --no-check-certificate -O /dev/null --quiet -t 1 https://domain/folder/cron.php`

Comment: Try installing schedule tasks so you can run multiple cronjobs easily, adding your cronjob to root user (for test), environment is minimum for crontab so make use of full paths or pass the env yourself. Verify permissions on all files involved.

Comment: you can also output the results to a terminal window: run "tty" output "/dev/pts/NUMBER" and redirect output to it after your command on the cronjob "* * * * * cmd > /dev/pts/NUMBER" or to a file and watch the file change.

Comment: vrs I did what you said me and it works! Thank you very much! Thank you Alan for your help too.

Comment: @AlvaroArjona Glad that it worked! I summed up my comments to you as an answer to this topic -- with some more details about wget options I sggeted you to use. Please, accept the answer, so that other people with the same problem would find a solution easily. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your redirect directive in 000-default.conf is correct (see [Apache wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) for details) and doesn't interfere with configuration in `.htaccess` file, if there is any.

Then fix you crontab this way:

1. Remove the first line, as you don't need plain http anymore
2. Change the second line for this:

   wget --no-check-certificate -O /dev/null --quiet -t 1 https://domain/folder/cron.php

`wget`'s option `-O` requires a path to a file, so either specify it, or just redirect to `/dev/null`. Also, in some versions of `wget` option `-q` considered ambiguous, so it's better to use `--quiet` to supress output instead.

Sometimes you may want to put your rather  longish command into a shell script file, make it executable (chmod +x your-script.sh) and make sure it does exactly what you want it to do when run under the webserver's user (sudo -u www-data /path/to/your-script.sh and check if it did the trick to your drupal module). Then use the path to your script in the crontab. That will ensure that everything works like a charm and will keep your crontab neat and valid.